# FormDataContentDisposition always bring undefined filename

Tags: upload, jersey

I'm trying to create a RESTfull service using jersey to upload files.
Reading the documentation I find out that I can use FormDataContentDisposition to get the uploaded file's details.

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response updateAccount(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    ...
}
```

Im using postman to test my service. The request's content made by postman is this

```
POST /myProject/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic MToxMjM0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 86255498-5aff-4b35-4b74-d7ec59759489
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryp7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myFile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

The problem is that filename is always "undefined" and i don't know how to get the file's mime type.